# Organization wide shared folder using onedrive for Business

Tags: sharepoint, office365, onedrive

I want to have a hierarchy of folders with restricted access by AD groups, is this possible using Onedrive for Business?

the folder Hierarchy is indicated in the below image

[image]

Finance Users should not have access to folders belonging to IT. similarly for other folders

Please let me know if this is possible with OneDrive for Business?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The end result can be achieved using One Drive for business but its not recommended. As One drive is a person's personal space and will be deleted when he/she leaves the organization.

The recommended approach will be using a SharePoint site and having different document libraries to achieve the same and you can have security groups which will be your AD groups here the group should be of type "Security Group". then its a matter of doing permission management using SharePoint.